# ASP.Net Log Response to Output File

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Occaisionally our office printer craps out on us in the middle of a print job, or someone just forgets to print because they get interrupted. In the good 'ole days, I built up my response using a StringBuilder and output the contents to the screen and to a log file in case we ever needed to go back and re-print.

Now I'm working with a system that makes use of all the .Net yumminess (Repeaters, page events, etc) rather than building up the HTML in code. Is there a way for me to log/archive the entire HTML response generated by the server for a particular page (e.g. hook into the Page_Render event and dump the output to a file)?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an Http Module that plugs in at the end of the request pipeline and records the complete output.

See [this example](http://heyse.us/blog/?p=120) that should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Any examples or references? I'd be interested in doing this.